# Downloading two outputs in R shiny with one Button

Tags: r, shiny, download

I need to download two files with a single click of a button (instead of two buttons). This is easy to do indepedently; however, I'm finding it near impossible for this with only one button. In the app example below, `write.csv(mtcarss_3(), file = file)` gets executed inside the `downloadHandler`; however, not the `write.csv(mtcarss_4(), file = file)` part. Is it possible to do this in Shiny? If so, how? Thanks for your help

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("mtcars df gear == 4"),
  h3("mtcars df gear == 3"),
  downloadButton("gears", "download both tables")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveVal("gears_3")
  
  mtcarss <- reactive(
    mtcars
  )
  
  mtcarss_3 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
     
    mtcarss() %>% 
      filter(gear == 3) %>% 
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  mtcarss_4 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
    
    mtcarss() %>% 
      filter(gear == 4) %>% 
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  output$gears <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears_3.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss_3(), file = file)
      write.csv(mtcarss_4(), file = file)
    }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In this kind of case, usually we compress files into one zip file and point that new zip for the users to download. One-click to download multiple files is also deprecated in most browsers. It is allowed but it raises security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip all files then download the zip file instead of trying to make multiple downloads at once:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("mtcars df gear == 4"),
  h3("mtcars df gear == 3"),
  downloadButton("gears", "download both tables")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveVal("gears_3")

  mtcarss <- reactive(
    mtcars
  )

  mtcarss_3 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())

    mtcarss() %>%
      filter(gear == 3) %>%
      pull(mpg)
  })

  mtcarss_4 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())

    mtcarss() %>%
      filter(gear == 4) %>%
      pull(mpg)
  })

  output$gears <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'files.zip',
    content = function(fname) {
      tmpdir <- tempdir()
      setwd(tempdir())

      fs <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
      write.csv(mtcarss_3(), file = "file1.txt", sep =",")
      write.csv(mtcarss_4(), file = "file2.txt", sep =",")

      zip(zipfile=fname, files=fs)
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I know bundling the files into a zip file might be the only the only way to do this now, but can you render an pdf from rmarkdown and a text file at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `downloadButton` to an `actionButton` and I am using a `numericInput` to choose how many files to download. You can easily change this to a `selectInput/textInput/pickerInput` using file names and change the loop that is downloading the files.

the `actionButton` leads to a loop where the `downloadButtons` are clicked using `shinyjs` package's `click` function. Re. the `downloadButtons` you could code them into your apps UI as before but put them all inside one hidden div, but instead, here I dynamically generated them based on how many files the user wants from the server. This is not necessary at all. You could just as well have hard coded them. The reason I used the `insertUI` and `removeUI` was due to a different solution I started with but ended instead with `shinyjs` which was much simpler.

When you click on the `actionButton` the number of files you wanted will download.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  h3("mtcars df gear == 4"),
  h3("mtcars df gear == 3"),
  numericInput("num_files", "Number of tables", value = 3, min = 1, max = 3),
  actionButton("gears_dloads", "download tables"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveVal("gears_3")
  
  # Observe that dynamically generates and removes UI based on the numericInput
  observe({
    if(is.na(input$num_files) || input$num_files <= 0 || input$num_files > 3){
      removeUI(
        selector = (".hidden-div"), #remove all the divs with class hidden-div
        multiple = TRUE,
        immediate = TRUE
      )
    }
    else if(input$num_files >0 &&input$num_files <= 3){
      for (i in 1:input$num_files)){
        # keep inserting hidden UIs
        insertUI(
          selector = paste0("#gears_dloads"), # select the id gears_download relative to where the new UI elements will go
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = div(downloadButton(paste0("gears_dload_",i),""), style = "visibility:hidden;",class="hidden-div")
        )
      }
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gears_dloads, {
    req(input$num_files)
    if(input$num_files > 0 && input$num_files <=3){
      for (i in 1:input$num_files) {
        shinyjs::click(paste0("gears_dload_",i))
      }
    }
  })
  
  mtcarss <- reactive(
    mtcars
  )
  
  
  mtcarss_3 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
    
    mtcarss() %>% 
      filter(gear == 3) %>% 
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  mtcarss_4 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
    
    mtcarss() %>% 
      filter(gear == 4) %>% 
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  output$gears_dload_1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss(), file = file)
    }
  )
  
  output$gears_dload_2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears_3.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss_3(), file = file)
    }
  )
  
  output$gears_dload_3 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears_4.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss_4(), file = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is the error I get: `object 'output' not found`

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, multiple files downloads are definitely not on the best practices of UX, but there are cases it might be needed.

With some JS magic you can do it:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790843/downloading-two-outputs-in-r-shiny-with-one-button
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("mtcars df gear == 4"),
  h3("mtcars df gear == 3"),
  downloadButton("gears", "download both tables", onclick = "document.getElementById('gears_4').click()"),
  downloadButton("gears_4", "download both tables",  style = "opacity: 0; position: fixed; pointer-events:none;")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveVal("gears_3")
  
  mtcarss <- reactive(mtcars)
  
  mtcarss_3 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
    
    mtcarss() %>%
      filter(gear == 3) %>%
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  mtcarss_4 <- reactive({
    req(mtcarss())
    
    mtcarss() %>%
      filter(gear == 4) %>%
      pull(mpg)
  })
  
  output$gears <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears_3.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss_3(), file = file)
    }
  )
  # Separate downloadHandler
  output$gears_4 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"gears_4.txt"},
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcarss_4(), file = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is simple: have separated download buttons, hide the extra button but trigger it with Javascript.

Tested and worked with Chrome Version 105.0.5195.127 (Official Build) (64-bit). Although it did asked for confirmation.